# aws-sdk-go-v2: Connect with localstack

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-sqs, aws-sdk-go

Hi i am trying to connect by go app with the sqs running on localstack
The localstack side is working proper

I do the following after reading [this](https://aws.github.io/aws-sdk-go-v2/docs/code-examples/sqs/receivemessage/)

```
cfg, err := config.LoadDefaultConfig(context.TODO(), config.WithRegion("us-east-1"), config.WithHTTPClient(&http.Client{Transport: &http.Transport{
    TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true}}}), config.WithEndpointResolver(
    aws.EndpointResolverFunc(func(service, region string) (aws.Endpoint, error) {
        return aws.Endpoint{
            PartitionID:       "aws",
            URL:               "http://127.0.0.1:4566",
            SigningRegion:     "us-east-1",
            HostnameImmutable: true,
        }, nil
    }),
))

if err != nil {
    log.Err(err).Msg("ERROR - 1")
    return nil
}
svc := sqs.NewFromConfig(cfg, func(o *sqs.Options) {
    o.HTTPClient = s{http.Client{}},
})
log.Info().Msg(qURL)
gQInput := &sqs.GetQueueUrlInput{
    QueueName: &qURL,
}

urlResult, err := GetQueueURL(context.TODO(), svc, gQInput)
if err != nil {
    log.Err(err).Msg("ERROR - 2")
    return nil
}
```

I get the following error with `GetQueueURL` call `operation error SQS: GetQueueUrl, exceeded maximum number of attempts, 3, https response error StatusCode: 0`

Is there an option to Disable HTTPS check?

Here is the localstack docker yml

```
version: '3.0'

services:

  localstack:
image: localstack/localstack:latest
environment:
  - AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
  - EDGE_PORT=4566
  - SERVICES=sqs
ports:
  - '4566:4566'
volumes:
  - "${TMPDIR:-/tmp/localstack}:/tmp/localstack"
  - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
```

I do not see any logs in the docker for the request

Comment: Can you please share more details about your localstack setup and share if there are any logs about your current problem? Do you use docker env for localstack?

Comment: @İlkerKorkut edited, added the localstack yml and I see normal logs for it, but nothing when the called within the go app